# I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument with I18n.l

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I get this error `I18n::MissingInterpolationArgument` when running this code

```
<%= l Date.today, :format => :short %>
```

It has worked before, but now, at Ubuntu, with `Rails 2.3.5` and `Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]` it doesn't work anymore ...

Anyone to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, got a quickfix for myself. Not the way I would have it, but it works

Added this to the en.yml file

```
  date:                   
    formats:              
      default: "%d.%m.%Y" 
      short: "%b %e"      
      long: "%e. %B %Y"
```